# Testng parse suite file to create multiple suite files of test

Tags: testng

I would like to know how I can parse the suite file in testng and extract all the classes with the intended tag from it.

For example,

```
<suite thread-count="5" verbose="1" name="Regression Suite" skipfailedinvocationcounts="false" junit="false" parallel="classes" data-provider-thread-count="1" annotations="JDK" preserve-order="false">
    <test name="RQA Set" parallel="classes">
        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="P1"></include>
            </run>
        </groups>
        <packages>
            <package name="com.test.regression" />
            <package name="com.test.regression1" />
        </packages>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Here, to extract the classes with tag P1 . Any help is much appreciated?

Comment: could you please explain little bit more. i hope provided testng.xml file good and works fine.

Comment: I would like to read the testng.xml programmatically and then read all the class names that need to be run as part of the suite file.  For example,
1.Read this suite file
2. Scan the packages to get all the tests
3. Filter all the tests which are tagged with "P1"

Answer (score 0):

I would say that there is another way to do that easily.
TestNG provides some listeners that you can modify its behavior at runtime
Then you can use java reflection framework to get class name of each test method which  belongs to. I think ISuiteListener is good for this case

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as,

- By defined specified Test in TestNG.XML suite,

How to create selected TestNG suite,

### **TestNG.XMl Suite Definition:**

**By Class:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test thread-count="5" name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="package1.test1"/>
      <class name="package2.test2"/>
      <class name="package6.test6"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

If you wish to include package, you can do it as :

**By Package:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
        <test name="TesteEmo">
            <packages>
                <package name="package4"></package>
            </packages>
        </test> <!-- Test -->
    </parameter>
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```